# Is dhparam really required if only using ECDHE?

Tags: ssl

https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html says there is a bunch of problems with DHE. It says it can be fixed by generating my own dhparams, but I'd rather not have to do this. I *think* ECDHE doesn't use dhparams, but the man page of `openssl dhparam` was less than clear on this point.

So, could ECDHE use dhparams? If so, and I am using ECDHE, should I generate my own dhparams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dhparam` is only used to generate the parameters for "classic" DH key exchange. It is not used in ECC based DH, i.e. not used with ECDHE ciphers. Thus, if no plain DH/DHE ciphers are configured at your server but only ECDHE then you don't need to set your own dhparam.